# Handling Apple Watch sensors data in WatchKit app

Tags: ios, sensors, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm reading several articles and Apple's documents regarding `Apple Watch` and `WatchKit` development. It looks like third-party apps for `Apple Watch` like `Strava` and `Runtastic` will need you to also carry your `iPhone` while doing exercise to take and show data (as described in [App Store Apps](http://www.apple.com/watch/app-store-apps/)), but I don't find if the built-in apps (`Activity` and `Workout`) will also need it. It looks a bit uncomfortable having to carry your `iPhone` while running to be able to see your heart rate, speed and so on in the watch...

Regarding the data measured by the heart rate sensor and accelerometer integrated in the `Apple Watch`: is there an API that makes them accessible to third-parties developers?

And how is data mesaured by those sensors handled by the watch: is it directly sent to the paired `iPhone` as it is measured? It is temporarily and locally persisted in the watch until it is possible to send it to the `iPhone`? Is `HealthKit` available for `WatchKit` apps to handle such information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858667/heart-rate-data-on-apple-watch/31165510#31165510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played with the Apple Watch at the Apple Watch lab.

The sensors and accelerometer are not accessible to devs.

You can go running without your phone and when you get home the heart rate data will 'eventually' be sent to Health on your phone, from which you can query data for your app.  Any heart rate or sensor data saved on the Apple Watch cache is not accessible to dev.

Answer (score 6):

Watchkit Sensor raw data information is **now accessible** with `WatchKit for watchOS 2.0`.

`WatchOS 2` includes many enhancements to other existing frameworks such as `HealthKit`, enabling access to the health sensors that access heart rate and health information in real-time.

You could check this information in the following session which is total 30 minutes presentation. If you do not want to watch entire session, then you directly jump to `Healthkit API` features which is in between 25-28 min:

[**WatchKit watchOS 2.0 Session in WWDC 2015**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=105)