# watchOS 2 Heart Rate Sensor

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, xcode7, watchos-2, watchos

Does anyone know how to access the heart rate sensor available in watchOS 2 in Xcode 7 beta?

Comment: This question needs improvement. What have you got so far? or are you just looking for a recommendation?

Comment: I am looking for a recommendation

Comment: Can someone point out the relevant document in apple developers that shows how to access the heart rate sensor on the apple watch?

Comment: Googled it for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=programming+WatchOS+2+heart+rate+sensor&oq=programming+WatchOS+2+heart+rate+sensor&gs_l=serp.3...4628.6781.0.8181.13.9.0.1.1.0.341.1174.2-2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..9.4.933.x6O9vtxtgL4

Comment: I have source code. Is it appropriate to post on StackOverflow while xcode 7 and watchos 2 are in beta stages?

Comment: please post the source code!

Answer (score 7):

watchOS 2 allows you to use [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=HealthKit). Within this kit, you may use [HKWorkout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkout_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014744) to access variables such as the heart rate.

Answer (score 4):

Apple isn't technically giving developers access to the heart rate sensors in watchOS 2.0. What they are doing is providing direct access to heart rate data recorded by the sensor in HealthKit. See the stack overflow answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776331/watch-os-2-0-beta-access-heart-beat-rate/31864640#31864640) for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

> Many of software kits for iOS are now available for watchOS, such as
>   HealthKit.

You can use HealthKit (HK) functions and classes in order to calculate burned calories, find heart rate, etc.

You can use `HKWorkout` to calculate everything about workouts and access the related variables such as heart rate, just like you did with iOS before.

Read developer documentations from Apple in order to learn about HealthKit. They can be found in [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com).

**Resources**

For more details about `HKWorkout`, you should check out the [HKWorkout Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkout_Class/) and the [HKWorkoutSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkoutSession_ClassReference/) from Apple.

Also don't forget to check out [this great WWDC15 video.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=105)

Comment: This answers is too vague, would be great to have an example or a link to a example.

Comment: I have edited the question to something more interesting and not vague. I have also added links to class references from Apple and a WWDC15 video.