# How to avoid keeping watch app in front when using HKWorkoutSession?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

I have developed an iPhone app with watch app for getting live stream of heart rate. As mentioned in many stackoverflow threads [iOS get heart rate from Apple Watch in near real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039742/ios-get-heart-rate-from-apple-watch-in-near-real-time), i have used **HKWorkoutSession** to get the updated heart rate and sending it to server **(Workout session will always be active to get live stream of heart rate)**.

The issue here is, this application always stays in front of watch app(which is the expected behaviour when we use **HKWorkoutSession**). But i don't want this behaviour to happen, since the app only does the job of getting heart rate updates and sending it to server.

My app now sends the heart rate correctly to server even when the watch screen is off and when the app is in background since i have used **Required** **background modes (Watch) in info.plist**.

Is there any way that we can avoid this app being in front of watch face every-time the user opens the watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid making you app frontmost while in a workout session on watchOS. You should [file a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to request an API with the behavior you want for your app.