# Access Live Health Info from Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit

So I'm basically experimenting with a chatbot ai thing and I want to add a feature for it to read my heart rate and see how good asleep I got last night etc. I'm thinking this could work by using my apple watch but one issue: how do I access the data?

I've seen a health kit but this is a python program I'm developing not an iOS app. Is there really no other way?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Related - looks like you need an app that streams live data in the background: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522069/60462