# How do I get this the currentStandHour value in Apple Watch iOS?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to retrieve the value that indicates whether or not the user has stood this hour. I also want to be able to retrieve the *StandHours* count for the day.

Here are the Apple links that I've been trying to understand in order get the value from [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit). I provide these links to help provide understanding for what I'm looking for and also to help you answer my question.

- `appleStandHour` type property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifier/1615539-applestandhour
- HealthKit category type identifier: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifier
- HealthKit constants: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/healthkit_constants

Bruno's answer is only half of the answer. For example, his `standUnit` variable is how he pulls the # of hours that the user has stood today. I tested it. Also, I made the assumption that it had to be pulled from within the scope of the summaries variable.

I have found another question on StackOverflow that might provide some clues. I think they managed to pull a value via a `HKCategoryTypeIdentifier`: [Watch os 2.0 beta: access heart beat rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776331/watch-os-2-0-beta-access-heart-beat-rate)

Here's my attempted code as far as I have been able to get:

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit
import HealthKitUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let hkStoreOnVC : HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    authorizeHealthKit()
    hkTest()
    hkTest2()
}

func authorizeHealthKit() {   //-> Bool {
    print("health kit authorize?")
    
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    
    let objectTypes: Set<HKObjectType> = [
        HKObjectType.activitySummaryType()
    ]
    
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: objectTypes) { (success, error) in
        
        // Authorization request finished, hopefully the user allowed access!
        print("health kit authorized")
    }
}

func hkTest() {
    print("health kit test.")
    
    let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    
    var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(
        [ .year, .month, .day ],
        from: Date()
    )
    
    // This line is required to make the whole thing work
    dateComponents.calendar = calendar
    
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary(with: dateComponents)
    
    //----------------------
    
    let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: predicate) { (query, summaries, error) in
        print("query")
        guard let summaries = summaries, summaries.count > 0
            else {
                print("no summaries")
                return
        }
        
        // Handle data
        
        for thisSummary in summaries {
            //                print("for each summary")
            let standUnit = HKUnit.count()
            let standHours = thisSummary.appleStandHours.doubleValue(for: standUnit)
            print("stand hours \(standHours)")
        }//end for
    } //end query
}

func hkTest2() {
    var isEnabled = true
    print ("authorize health kit" )
    if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        let stepsCount  = NSSet(objects: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount ) )
        
        for thisValue in stepsCount {
            //              thisValue.
            print("thisValue: \(thisValue)")
        }

        print(" authorize HK - steps count \(stepsCount) ")
    }
    
    // Create the date components for the predicate
    guard let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian) else {
        fatalError("*** This should never fail. ***")
    }
    
    let endDate = NSDate()
    
    guard let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: endDate as Date, options: []) else {
        fatalError("*** unable to calculate the start date ***")
    }
    
    let units: NSCalendar.Unit = [.day, .month, .year, .era]
    
    var startDateComponents = calendar.components(units, from: startDate)
    startDateComponents.calendar = calendar as Calendar
    
    var endDateComponents = calendar.components(units, from: endDate as Date)
    endDateComponents.calendar = calendar as Calendar
    
    // Create the predicate for the query
    let summariesWithinRange =  HKQuery.predicate(forActivitySummariesBetweenStart: startDateComponents, end: endDateComponents)
    
    // Build the query
    let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: summariesWithinRange) { (query, summaries, error) -> Void in
        guard let activitySummaries = summaries else {
            guard let queryError = error else {
                fatalError("*** Did not return a valid error object. ***")
            }
            
            // Handle the error here...
            return
        }
        
        for thisSummary in activitySummaries {
            //                print("for each summary")
            let standUnit = HKUnit.count()
            let standHours = thisSummary.appleStandHours.doubleValue(for: standUnit)
            //                let stoodThisHourMaybe = thisSummary.appleStandHours.categ //doubleValue(for: standUnit)
            //\(thisSummary.description) //stand unit _\(standUnit)_
            print("day#\(thisSummary.dateComponents(for: calendar as Calendar).day) stand hours \(standHours)  ")
        }//end for
        
        // Do something with the summaries here...
        
        for thisItem in activitySummaries {
            //thisItem.appleStandHours
            
            print("abc \( thisItem.appleStandHours ) " )
        }//end for
    }
    
    // Run the query
    let hkStore : HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
    hkStore.execute(query)
    
    //***
    let aStandHour =  HKCategoryType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .appleStandHour)
   
    // This is the type you want updates on. It can be any health kit type, including heart rate.
    //            let distanceType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning)
    
    // Match samples with a start date after the workout start
    //        let predicate =  .predicat //( , endDate: nil, options: .None)
    //        let theDate : Date =
    let thepredicate =  HKQuery.predicateForCategorySamples(with: .greaterThanOrEqualTo, value: 0) //.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate , endDate: nil, options: .None)
    //        predicate
    
    //        let predicate = .  //(theDate , endDate: nil, options: .None)
    let hka : HKQueryAnchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: 0)
    let sHourQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: aStandHour!, predicate: thepredicate, anchor: hka, limit: 0, resultsHandler: { ( query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        // Handle when the query first returns results
        // TODO: do whatever you want with samples (note you are not on the main thread)
        print("getting here A?")
        //            for thisSample in samples! {
        //                print("A smpLType \(thisSample.sampleType) thisSample \(thisSample)")
        //            }
    })
    
    // This is called each time a new value is entered into HealthKit (samples may be batched together for efficiency)
    
    sHourQuery.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        // Handle update notifications after the query has initially run
        // TODO: do whatever you want with samples (note you are not on the main thread)
        print("getting here B?")
        for thisSample in samples! {
            print("B smpLType \(thisSample.sampleType) thisSample \(thisSample)")
        }
    }
    
    // Start the query
    self.hkStoreOnVC.execute(sHourQuery)
    //***
    
}//end func

func myCompletionHandler(bTest: Bool ) {
    print("my completion handler")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}//end viewController Class
```

Here's the code output - the log never prints to "getting here b?":

```
health kit authorize?
health kit test.
authorize health kit
health kit authorized
thisValue: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount
 authorize HK - steps count {(
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount
)} 
2017-11-04 19:18:30.100562-0500 watchapptest[25048:4695625] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
2017-11-04 19:18:30.100600-0500 watchapptest[25048:4695625] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-11-04 19:18:30.100615-0500 watchapptest[25048:4695625] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
getting here A?
day#Optional(28) stand hours 14.0  
day#Optional(29) stand hours 14.0  
day#Optional(30) stand hours 14.0  
day#Optional(31) stand hours 14.0  
day#Optional(1) stand hours 16.0  
day#Optional(2) stand hours 13.0  
day#Optional(3) stand hours 15.0  
day#Optional(4) stand hours 13.0  
abc 14 count 
abc 14 count 
abc 14 count 
abc 14 count 
abc 16 count 
abc 13 count 
abc 15 count 
abc 13 count
```

Answer (score 3):

I am new to HealthKit, so there probably is a nicer way to do this. But this seems to work for me. I check the actually standing minutes and call the completion handler with `minutes > 0`.

```
    private let store = HKHealthStore()

    func askPermission() {
        let standType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .appleStandTime)!
        store.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [standType], completion: { (success, error) in
            self.didStandThisHour { (didStand) in
                print("Did stand this hour: \(didStand)")
            }
        })
    }

    func didStandThisHour(_ didStand: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let store = HKHealthStore()
        let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: Date())
        let endDate = Date()
        let startDate = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
        let standTime = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.appleStandTime)!
        var interval = DateComponents()
        interval.hour = 1
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
        let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: standTime, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: startDate, intervalComponents:interval)
        query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
            guard error == nil, let myResults = results else {
                fatalError("Something is wrong with HealthKit link")
            }
            myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate, with: { (statistics, stop) in
                guard let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() else {
                    didStand(false)
                    return
                }
                let minutes = quantity.doubleValue(for: .minute())
                didStand(minutes > 0)
            })
        }
        store.execute(query)
    }
```

Comment: I found out this approach is not 100% reliable. Sometimes the minutes are still zero although the stand hours in activity has already been checked off. I don't know if this has something to do with HealthKit synchronization or not. Maybe there is a small delay to when a standing minute is added to HealthKit

Comment: Thanks.  I did stop looking at this when the watch got updated to again to show whether or not you've stood this hour.  For a minor version or two, apple watch wasn't showing if your current stand goal was achieved.  Which is why I was interested in building a watch app to re-show this indicator.

Comment: Why not use this with seconds instead of minutes? Maybe that's why it has false negatives.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if you want to retrieve today's activity ring info (including stand hours) you first request user authorization for the object type you want to retrieve:

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

let objectTypes: Set<HKObjectType> = [
    HKObjectType.activitySummaryType()
]

healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: objectTypes) { (success, error) in

    // Authorization request finished, hopefully the user allowed access!
}
```

Then you can use this predicate to retrieve today's date:

```
let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent

var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(
    [ .year, .month, .day ],
    from: Date()
)

// This line is required to make the whole thing work
dateComponents.calendar = calendar

let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary(with: dateComponents)
```

Create a query...

```
let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: predicate) { (query, summaries, error) in

    guard let summaries = summaries, summaries.count > 0
    else {
        return
    }

    // Handle data
}
```

The data you'll receive is of type [HKActivitySummary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkactivitysummary) and you can retrieve, for example:

```
let sandUnit = HKUnit.count()
let standHours = summary.appleStandHours.doubleValue(for: standUnit)
```

Comment: I need the value that indicates whether they stood in the current hour.

Comment: Your answer isn't full.  The current stand hour is the hard part and nobody online gives an example of how to get it.

Comment: you can specify that in the dateComponents variable, try and get the current hour there.
edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927028/how-do-i-get-hour-and-minutes-from-nsdate

Comment: Please re-read my question(s) as you still haven't answered my main question.  I'll try to explain further too.  

The Apple Watch stores TWO seperate values.  
StandHour, which is = to whether or not I stood this hour.  AND it stores StandHours which = how many hours I stood today.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out how to do this!? Ie: get the AppleStandHour for CURRENT HOUR?