# How to access the heart rate and the physical activity data from HealthKit in background mode?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-2

I'm working on a app that needs the user's heart rate and physical activity data every hour or so from HealthKit and analyse it and notify the user of a high heart rate streak, all this has to happen when the app is not opened and running (when the app is terminated).

I would like to know if this is possible and how can I access those values?
How can I run the code in background mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply use HealthKit. Check out Apple's WWDC15 videos for more info. developer.apple.com/wwdc. See Introducing WatchKit for watchOS 2, and What's new in HealthKit. You will find a lot of information.

Comment: I did check them out,I know that I can get the heart rate data my question in specific is can I get it in realtime without the user having to open the app,the app has must receive the data in the background.Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use complications (there are new in watchOS 2). They always run in the watch face and they can be updated manual or automatic. You can insert the code here, although you need to tell the user to include the complication. User doesn't need it, but you can provide data and then you can calculate your data. You can see manuals for complications in watchOS 2 Transition Guide and Introducing WatchKit for watchOS 2 video.

Comment: Thank you,I'll certainly look into it.

Comment: @Philip is correct. The only thing your user will need to do is the initial triggering of the HKWorkoutSession.

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858667/heart-rate-data-on-apple-watch/31165510#31165510

Comment: What I need is to access the user's heart rate that is been recorded every hour or so and analyse it and send the user a notification if there is a high streak in his heart rate.
I think I have the following options to do this...

1)I would love if this options works,the watch app for my app will receive the heart rate from health kit and work on it in background mode and notify the user

2)The iPhone app will tap into the health app that receives all the data from the watch and in the background(even when the app is terminated) it will analyse it and notify the user.

Answer (score 2):

Apps on watchOS 2.0 cannot run while in the background.  Your app must be foregrounded in order to query for the user's heart rate from HealthKit.

Comment: Yes,now the only option I have is to have a background task run on the iPhone app that gets all the data from health kit and work on it.
You can also know the source of the data,so that's good.
I'm looking in to this specific thing called "HealthKit Background Delivery".

Comment: The background delivery feature of HealthKit is not available on watchOS.

Comment: Yes,that's pretty limiting, but the iPhone app can just simply receive the heart rate data from the health app which in turn gets it from the watch.

Comment: @PrithivDev were you able to read live heart rate data coming from WatchOS on iOS even when the watch screen was turned off?

Comment: I wasn't able to read it when the watch screen was turned off. The only way is to use HealthKit's background delivery method, that is every time a new data entry is made in the Health app, your iOS app in the background receives it and you can have a method triggered automatically which can work on the data, send notifications or send data to the watch app using watch connectivity. It's kind of a stretch but for now it's the only way to go.

Comment: Note that background delivery mode in iOS will only work for HealthKit if the screen is unlocked OR the device does not have a passcode set. If a passcode is set and the screen is off, the device encrypts the health kit database. You can still get notifications that data has changed, but you are not able to query to see what Health kit data has changed.