# HKworkoutSession Heartrate updating freqency

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit, watchos-2

I am doing some pre-learning about watchOS2 and having a question about HKworkoutSession.

I am able to start HKworkoutSession and read heart rate data from sensor. But how could I control data updating frequency?

In the build-in heartrate measuring app on the apple watch, heart rate updates approximately per 5 second.

Is there any way to decrease the frequency?

Thanks

Comment: check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858667/heart-rate-data-on-apple-watch/31165510#31165510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly control the frequency of heart rate readings on the watch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you confirm that current updating frequency for heartrate sensor is 5 seconds?Because I just kind of measured it manually with a stop watch.